# Is Hide My Email really a replacement for a normal account?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, apple-id, messages-in-icloud

I was thinking about [Hide My Email](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/what-you-can-do-with-icloud-and-hide-my-email-mme38e1602db/icloud) as a replacement for a normal e-mail account. However I'm not sure anymore.

Tried to create an account on [www.interactivebrokers.com](http://www.interactivebrokers.com) and looks like the confirmation e-mail never arrives. So Hide My Email addresses might be being blocked somehow. How they might be identifying and blocking them?

Comment: It's not like it would be hard to figure out how Apple is anonymizing the email, and just block those servers.

Comment: Given that I have to ask, what would be one way to try to identify a `Hide My Email` address?

Comment: From the email headers.  Servers aren't an infinite resource, while the messages come from multiple IP address blocks that probably aren't part of Apple's /8, it's not like they can come from a random IP picked from 16 billion possibles.

Answer (score 1):

I had very similar issue, but with other broker service - XTB. Their mails have never arrived to me after moving my domain to iCloud Mail. To investigate that, I've registered on some mail "proxy" service (receives mails and passes them further where you want) and I found that Apple in fact rejects their messages (as they weren't complying to Apple's deliverability requirements), as my proxy provider had in logs that they received that mail, but Apple rejected their attempt to deliver this mail to iCloud. And the same story was with the most finances-related services (crypto, etc.).

The only info they give you is this [url](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204137), but they don't mention which particular rule sender's mail server has broken.

After all of that, I have moved my whole domain to a different provider, as Apple doesn't really give you ability to fix those issues, and they don't even notify You about such issues.

Comment: Side question: I would like to know more about `some mail "proxy" service (receives mails and passes them further where you want)`, would you recommend one of those servers?

Comment: I used ImprovMX, but be aware that I didn't really do any good research in that matter, so it may be not the best choice. Its free plan was ideal for my debugging needs.